# Eureka form connecting with custom tableview?

Tags: ios, swift, eureka-forms

Does anyone know how to create Eureka form with custom tableview? I created tableview using storyboard but cannot find how to connect with eureka. I want this because i have custom header above tableview. But if i create with programmatically, eureka form uses its own design without my custom header view.

Comment: You can have a custom header view by setting HeaderFooterView for Section

Comment: thanks, i will look how to use

Answer (score 0):

For Custom Header You create your own header nib or UIView

**Using nib file**

```
Section() { section in
var header = HeaderFooterView<MyHeaderNibFile>(.nibFile(name: "MyHeaderNibFile", bundle: nil))

// Will be called every time the header appears on screen
header.onSetupView = { view, _ in
    // Commonly used to setup texts inside the view
    // Don't change the view hierarchy or size here!
}
section.header = header
}
```

**Using UIView**

```
Section(){ section in
var header = HeaderFooterView<MyCustomUIView>(.class)
header.height = {100}
header.onSetupView = { view, _ in
    view.backgroundColor = .red
}
section.header = header
}
```

for more [Section Header and Footer](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka#section-header-and-footer)

Answer (score 0):

you can connect via outlet: check the link: [official explanation page](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka#how-to-set-up-your-form-from-a-storyboard)

> You can set up your view controller in a storyboard and add a UITableView where you want it to be and then connect the outlet to FormViewController's tableView variable. This allows you to define a custom frame (possibly with constraints) for your form.